# Python3 program is going in Not Responding state

Tags: python-3.x, oop, pyqt5

I have two python files **"main.py"** and **"mainLauncher.py"** in the same folder.
I am making an application so If I run **mainLauncher.py** then It is running successfully and opening a window as shown below.

[image: By running mainLauncher.py]

The code for **mainLauncher.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainLauncher(object):

    def main_launcher_ui(self, WizardPage):

        WizardPage.setObjectName("WizardPage")
        WizardPage.resize(626, 284)
        WizardPage.setStyleSheet("background-color:#e0e0e0;\n"
                                 "border:none;")
        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(WizardPage)
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 601, 51))
        self.textBrowser.viewport().setProperty("cursor", QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.IBeamCursor))
        self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("border:none;\n"
                                       "color:#424242 ;\n"
                                       "font-family:futura light;\n"
                                       "")
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
        self.next = QtWidgets.QPushButton(WizardPage)
        self.next.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(390, 240, 84, 28))
        self.next.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.next.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid #ccc;\n"
                                "background: QLinearGradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ccc, stop: 1 #fff);")
        self.next.setObjectName("next")
        self.quit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(WizardPage)
        self.quit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(490, 240, 84, 28))
        self.quit.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.quit.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid #ccc;\n"
                                "background: QLinearGradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1, stop: 0 #ccc, stop: 1 #fff);")
        self.quit.setObjectName("quit")
        self.retranslateUi(WizardPage
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(WizardPage)

    def retranslateUi(self, WizardPage):

        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        WizardPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "WizardPage"))
        self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("WizardPage",
                                            "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                            "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                            "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                            "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'futura 53\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                            "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Cantarell\'; font-size:24pt; font-weight:600;\">Welcome to GDrive</span></p></body></html>"))
        self.next.setText(_translate("WizardPage", "Next"))
        self.quit.setText(_translate("WizardPage", "Quit"))

def retranslateUi(self, WizardPage):

    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    WizardPage.setWindowTitle(_translate("WizardPage", "WizardPage"))
    self.textBrowser.setHtml(_translate("WizardPage",
                                        "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
                                        "<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
                                        "p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
                                        "</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'futura 53\'; font-size:11pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
                                        "<p style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\"><span style=\" font-family:\'Cantarell\'; font-size:24pt; font-weight:600;\">Welcome to GDrive</span></p></body></html>"))
    self.next.setText(_translate("WizardPage", "Next"))
    self.quit.setText(_translate("WizardPage", "Quit"))

def main_launch():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    WizardPage = QtWidgets.QWizardPage()
    ui = Ui_MainLauncher()
    ui.main_launcher_ui(WizardPage)
    WizardPage.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
main_launch()
```

Now If I remove calling of **main_launch()** function from **mainLauncher.py** and call it from **main.py**. So I made **main.py** as :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from mainLauncher import main_launch

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
main_launch()  # calling of main_launch() which is in mainLaunch.py
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

But If I am running **main.py** then the window is going in **Not Responding** state and I have to kill the process from **task manager** and I am getting following output:

[image: By Running main.py]

Can anyone please tell me that Why is it happening and How can I resolve it? I want to run **main_launch()** from **main.py**.

Comment: I have tested your code and removed the retranslateUi function that I think you copied it in duplicate form without realizing it and it works correctly, you could share the complete code that generates the error through drive, dropbox or similar.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok this is google drive link:   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6dxEingt2ARUzFJbWhBQjdINk0?usp=sharing

Comment: You need Python3 and PyQt5 module to run this code.

Comment: I've run it with python3 and PyQt5 and it works fine. :P

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually I need to remove the last line from mainLauncher.py. This line calls the function which is we need to call from main.py.. So please try removing the last line from mainLauncher.py then run main.py. Then it will give unexpected result.

Comment: I have done what you indicate, but if you have doubts you could provide the code that generates the error through drive, dropbox, github or similar to be able to test.

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok I have replaced this code with the code which is generating the error. run main.py and then it will generate an error. this is the link for code https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B6dxEingt2ARUzFJbWhBQjdINk0?usp=sharing

Comment: try with my answer. :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can only be one instance of `QApplication` since it handles the main loop, but in your case you have created 2 generating the first block the second. To solve this we verify that only a new instance is created if it does not exist, for it changes the main.py to what I show next:

**main.py**

```
import sys    
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets    
from mainLauncher import main_launch

if QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

main_launch()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```